# use array/variable in sql-query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure there is a way to do it but I don't know it anymore...

I have one big table with all the data.

In the `table I` have rows with information in:

```
    columnA1: groupName
    columnA2: groupID
    ColumnB3: name
    columnB4: groupID
```

Now I need to display the result like this:

```
[columnB3],[columnA1]
```

More information (because I don't have enough reputation I can't upload an image...):

**My table**:

```
groupId    - groupName     -  name      -  groupId2     -  category
   1       -   IT          -  null      -  null         -     2
   2       -   HR          -  null      -  null         -     2
   null    -  null         -  Paul      -  1            -     1
   null    -  null         -  Bob       -  1            -     1
   null    -  null         -  An        -  2            -     1
   null    -  null         -  Apple     -  null         -     3
   null    -  null         -  Microsift -  null         -     3
```

**Result of query:**

```
name    groupName

Paul      IT
Bob       IT
An        HR
```

If I select all my results I get `65k` rows. So how can i prevent that I need to do a query for every row to get the right groupName instead of the groupId2?

I thought I could "save" a first query, with all the groupID's and groupNames, and use this information to change the groupID to the groupName in my second query but I don't know how...

If it's not clear, just ask.

Edited: Need only the rows of category = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT T2.name,T1.groupName
FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN
Table1 T2 on T1.groupID=T2.groupId2
WHERE T2.category=1
```

Result:

```
NAME    GROUPNAME

Paul    IT
Bob     IT
An      HR
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79e22/1)

Comment: Is an inner join the best solution for 65k (or more) results?If yes, thanks!

Comment: @endeka: You have to join for a result like this, my friend. There is no problem.

Comment: I forgot to say, I also have a column "category" and I only need the rows with category =  1. How can I use a "where"? My current query (without the inner join) is: SELECT name, ID from table1 where category = 1

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:
`SELECT DISTINCT A.Groupname, B.name
FROM tablename A
JOIN tablename B ON A.GroupID = B.GroupID`