# extend SQL result - add row if not exist

Tags: sql

At the moment I have a query like this:

```
SELECT d.[status]
      ,d.[PGID] as PGID
      ,pg.[nvarchar5] as PGName
      ,COUNT(d.[nvarchar10])
FROM 
      [content].[dbo].[USRData] d
INNER JOIN
      [content].[dbo].[USRData] pg on d.[PGID] = pg.[tp_ID]
WHERE d.CatId = '12345'
      AND d.[nvarchar10] is not null
      AND d.[isActive] = 1
      AND pg.[CatId] = '64521'
GROUP BY
      pg.[nvarchar5]
     ,d.[status]
ORDER BY PGName
```

This is the result (just a fictive example):

```
status    PGID    PGName    Total
--------- ------- --------- ---------
active    10      HR        120
deleted   10      HR        5
new       10      HR        10
active    15      IT        10
new       15      IT        40
deleted   32      FI        12
new       32      FI        30
```

I need a query so the result should be like this:

```
status    PGID    PGName    Total
--------- ------- --------- ---------
active    10      HR        120
deleted   10      HR        5
new       10      HR        10
active    15      IT        10
deleted   15      IT        0
new       15      IT        40
active    32      FI        0
deleted   32      FI        12
new       32      FI        30
```

The difference is: I want for every PG a list of total for every possible status, even if it doesn't exist. If it doesn't exist I need a row like for example "deleted 15 IT 0"
I need to now every total of a possible status for every PG.

What do I need to change?

Edit:
More information

1. In the current query the inner join is on PGID and not status
2. about my table, an example: [use array/variable in sql-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475998/use-array-variable-in-sql-query/22476168?noredirect=1#comment34189932_22476168)

Update 2:
with this query I get better results, only the total is not correct...

```
SELECT stat.status
      ,d.[PGID] as PGID
      ,pg.[nvarchar5] as PGName
      ,COUNT(d.[nvarchar10])
FROM 
    (select distinct [status]
     from [content].[dbo].[USRData] 
     where  CatId = '1234') stat cross Join
      [content].[dbo].[USRData]  d INNER JOIN
      [content].[dbo].[USRData]  pg on d.[PGID] = pg.[tp_ID]
where d.CatId = '1234'
      AND d.[nvarchar10] is not null
      AND stat.status is not null
      AND d.[isActive] = 1
      AND pg.[CatId] = '64521'
group by stat.status, 
         pg.[nvarchar5], 
         d.[PGID]
order by PGName
```

With my example as above, this is what I get:

```
status    PGID    PGName    Total
--------- ------- --------- ---------
active    10      HR        135
deleted   10      HR        135
new       10      HR        135
active    15      IT        50
deleted   15      IT        50
new       15      IT        50
active    32      FI        42
deleted   32      FI        42
new       32      FI        42
```

I get the total for every PGName. How can I get the total for every PGName/status?

Answer (score 0):

You do this by creating the cartesian product of `status` and `PGID`.  You can get this from the table your are using.  In this case, I think the query is:

```
SELECT sall.[status], pgall.[PGID] as PGID, pg.[nvarchar5] as PGName, COUNT(d.[nvarchar10])
FROM (select distinct status from [content].[dbo].[USRData]) sall cross join
     (select distinct pgid from [content].[dbo].[USRData]) pgall left outer join
     [content].[dbo].[USRData] d
     on d.status = sall.status left outer join
     [content].[dbo].[USRData] pg
     on pg.[PGID] = pgall.[tp_ID]
where d.CatId = '12345' AND
      d.[nvarchar10] is not null AND
      d.[isActive] = 1 AND
      pg.[CatId] = '64521'
group by pgall.[nvarchar5], sall.[status]
order by PGName
```

I'm not 100% sure this is what you want, because you are taking `PGID` and `status` from the `d` table -- I don't fully understand the self join here.

Comment: Here is more information about my table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475998/use-array-variable-in-sql-query/22476168?noredirect=1#comment34189932_22476168

Comment: I tried the code but it's not working. Do you now understand the self join with the link above?

Answer (score 0):

Inner Join is issue in you query, it excludes Roles who don't have users, instead use Left join

```
SELECT d.[status]
  ,d.[PGID] as PGID
  ,pg.[nvarchar5] as PGName
  ,COUNT(d.[nvarchar10])
FROM [content].[dbo].[USRData] d Left JOIN
[content].[dbo].[USRData] pg on d.[PGID] = pg.[tp_ID]
where d.CatId = '12345'
AND d.[nvarchar10] is not null
AND d.[isActive] = 1
AND pg.[CatId] = '64521'
group by pg.[nvarchar5], d.[status]
order by PGName
```

Comment: In the current query the inner join is on PGID and not status. So this is not working.