# wrong number in count()

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I've already posted two questions about my problem and I'm almost there I think.

These are my older posts:

1. [use array/variable in sql-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475998/use-array-variable-in-sql-query)
2. [extend SQL result - add row if not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503369/extend-sql-result-add-row-if-not-exist)

It easier to explain it by an example, so this is the situation with a fictive example:

My table looks like this (I only show the rows I need, this table contains +100k rows)

```
status  PGID    nvarchar5               nvarchar10  CatId   tp_ID   isActive
IT      NULL    Information technology  NULL        1       1       1
HR      NULL    Human Recource          NULL        1       2       1
FIN     NULL    Finance                 NULL        1       3       1
New        1    NULL                    1354        2       10001   1
New        1    NULL                    464         2       10002   1
New        1    NULL                    13465       2       10003   1
Active     1    NULL                    79846       2       10004   1
Deleted    1    NULL                    132465      2       10005   1
New        2    NULL                    79847       2       10006   1
New        2    NULL                    341         2       10007   1
Deleted    2    NULL                    465         2       10008   1
Deleted    2    NULL                    132         2       10009   1
Deleted    2    NULL                    465         2       10010   1
Deleted    2    NULL                    1           2       10011   1
New        3    NULL                    465         2       10012   1
New        3    NULL                    1465        2       10013   1
New        3    NULL                    132         2       10014   1
NULL    NULL    NULL                    NULL        3       20136   1
NULL    NULL    NULL                    NULL        4       22165   1
NULL    NULL    NULL                    NULL        3       24566   1
```

And I use this query:

```
SELECT stat.status
      ,d.[PGID] as PGID
      ,pg.[nvarchar5] as PGName
      ,COUNT(d.[nvarchar10])
FROM 
    (select distinct [status]
     from [content].[dbo].[USRData] 
     where  CatId = '1') stat cross Join
      [content].[dbo].[USRData]  d INNER JOIN
      [content].[dbo].[USRData]  pg on d.[PGID] = pg.[tp_ID]
where d.CatId = '1'
      AND d.[nvarchar10] is not null
      AND stat.status is not null
      AND d.[isActive] = 1
      AND pg.[CatId] = '2'
group by stat.status, 
         pg.[nvarchar5], 
         d.[PGID]
order by PGName
```

Then I get this result:

```
status  PGID    nvarchar5               total
new     1       Information technology  5
active  1       Information technology  5
deleted 1       Information technology  5
new     2       Human Recource          6
active  2       Human Recource          6
deleted 2       Human Recource          6
new     3       Finance                 3
active  3       Finance                 3
deleted 3       Finance                 3
```

But I would like to have this result:

```
status  PGID    nvarchar5               total
new     1       Information technology  3
active  1       Information technology  1
deleted 1       Information technology  1
new     2       Human Recource          2
active  2       Human Recource          0
deleted 2       Human Recource          4
new     3       Finance                 3
active  3       Finance                 0
deleted 3       Finance                 0
```

I'm not a pro in SQL. Maybe it's something stupid but I'm stuck... Any help is welcome! :)

Comment: So you want to select all the rows where the column is not null????

Comment: Why did you tag this with `mysql` when it's clearly only for SQL Server?

Comment: What I want is for every PGID/nvarchar5 a list of total for every possible status, even if it doesn't exist. If it doesn't exist I need a row like for example "deleted 3 Finance 0". I need to now every total of a possible status for every PGID.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in the result you're seeking, there's less rows in the `total` column than the result given, it may be due to duplicated rows, I'm guessing the `CROSS JOIN` is responsible for it, why don't you try an `INNER JOIN` instead on `status`

```
(select distinct [status]
     from [content].[dbo].[USRData] 
      where  CatId = '1') stat 
     INNER JOIN [content].[dbo].[USRData]  d on stat.[status]=d.[status]
     INNER JOIN [content].[dbo].[USRData]  pg on d.[PGID] = pg.[tp_ID]
```

Comment: Hi, with inner join I don't have the 0 values... I also need for example "deleted 3 Finance 0"