# group by - counting rows and if not existing add row with 0 value

Tags: sql

I know I already asked a similar question, but here I start from zero... Without giving any query I tried so I don't influance you.

If this is my table:

```
status  PGID    nvarchar5               nvarchar10  CatId   tp_ID   isActive
IT      NULL    Information technology  NULL        1       1       1
HR      NULL    Human Recource          NULL        1       2       1
FIN     NULL    Finance                 NULL        1       3       1
New        1    NULL                    1354        2       10001   1
New        1    NULL                    464         2       10002   1
New        1    NULL                    13465       2       10003   1
Active     1    NULL                    79846       2       10004   1
Deleted    1    NULL                    132465      2       10005   1
New        2    NULL                    79847       2       10006   1
New        2    NULL                    341         2       10007   1
Deleted    2    NULL                    465         2       10008   1
Deleted    2    NULL                    132         2       10009   1
Deleted    2    NULL                    465         2       10010   1
Deleted    2    NULL                    1           2       10011   1
New        3    NULL                    465         2       10012   1
New        3    NULL                    1465        2       10013   1
New        3    NULL                    132         2       10014   1
NULL    NULL    NULL                    NULL        3       20136   1
NULL    NULL    NULL                    NULL        4       22165   1
NULL    NULL    NULL                    NULL        3       24566   1
NULL    NULL    NULL                    NULL        10      24566   1
```

What should be the query if I want a result like this:

```
status  PGID    nvarchar5               total
new     1       Information technology  3
active  1       Information technology  1
deleted 1       Information technology  1
new     2       Human Recource          2
active  2       Human Recource          0
deleted 2       Human Recource          4
new     3       Finance                 3
active  3       Finance                 0
deleted 3       Finance                 0
```

Or is this not possible?

Edit:
If you want to see what I've tried: [wrong number in count()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22530315/wrong-number-in-count)

Update:
How I calculate my total:
[image]

Comment: Don't expect people here to answer your question, without showing a minimum understanding of the problem. That means, you should definitely tell us what query you have tried so far. People here are pretty good at what they do - you shouldn't worry about us being "influenced" by your query attempt.

Comment: how did you derived to solution?                                                                 status  PGID    nvarchar5               total
new     1       Information technology  3

Comment: @Dan, ok no problem. This my other post with my queries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22530315/wrong-number-in-count

Comment: @Trinity: I have 3 because I have 3 rows with status new and PGID 1 in my table. I've added more information in my post

Answer (score 1):

I won't bother going into how bad the data looks, column names etc and will presume it's a case of 'this is what I have to work with'. So given the data try

```
SELECT t.Status, t.Department_ID, t.Department, COALESCE(s.Total, 0) AS Total
FROM (
    SELECT nvarchar5 AS Department, tp_ID AS Department_ID, Status
    FROM My_Table, 
         (SELECT 'new' AS Status
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 'active' AS Status
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 'deleted' AS Status ) AS m
    WHERE tp_ID IN (1,2,3)
) AS t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT status AS Status, PGID AS Department_ID, COUNT(1) AS Total
    FROM My_Table
    WHERE PGID IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY Status, PGID
) AS s 
ON t.Status = s.Status
AND t.Department_ID = s.Department_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not the answer, but I think this can help you too:

```
declare @t as table (
num varchar(50)  null,
t varchar(50) null,
ord int not null,
pgid int null
)

insert into @t values ('IT',  'Info', 1 ,   null)
insert into @t values ('HR' , 'Human', 2 ,   null)
insert into @t values ('FIN', 'Finance', 3 ,  null )
insert into @t values ('New'    , NULL, 10001,  1 )
insert into @t values ('New'    , NULL, 10002,  1 )
insert into @t values ('New'    , NULL, 10003,  1 )
insert into @t values ('Active' , NULL, 10004,  1 )
insert into @t values ('Deleted', NULL, 10005,  1 )
insert into @t values ('New'    , NULL, 10006,  2 )
insert into @t values ('New'    , NULL, 10007,  2 )
insert into @t values ('Deleted', NULL, 10008,  2 )
insert into @t values ('Deleted', NULL, 10009,  2 )
insert into @t values ('Deleted', NULL, 10010,  2 )
insert into @t values ('Deleted', NULL, 10011,  2 )
insert into @t values ('New'    , NULL, 10012,  3 )
insert into @t values ('New'    , NULL, 10013,  3 )
insert into @t values ('New'    , NULL, 10014,  3 )


select num, pgid, case when pgid = 1 then 'Information technology'
when pgid = 2 then 'Human Recource'
else 'Finance' end,count(num)
from @t
where num in (
'New'    ,
'Active' ,
'Deleted')
group by num, pgid


SELECT case when pgid = 1 then 'Information technology'
when pgid = 2 then 'Human Recource'
else 'Finance' end,
[New]    ,
[Active] ,
[Deleted]
FROM
(SELECT num, pgid 
    FROM @t
    where num in (
'New'    ,
'Active' ,
'Deleted')) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
count(num)
FOR num IN ([New],
[Active] ,
[Deleted])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this query it will help you to solve this problem

select t.satus,t.PGID,u.nvarchar5,t.total from 
    (select status,PGID,count(*) as total from USRData group by status,PGID where PGID is not null) t
    inner join USRData u on(t.PGID=u.tp_ID) where u.PGID is null and status is not null;
```